# I have connected my Stack Overflow account to Tex.SE and Meta.SE: Can't login with another device

Tags: support, login, accounts

One week ago I set up this SO account. I was active on the site. Then when I went to Tex.SE and I **logged on/connected using my SO account**.

Now I am on a different computer; logged on to SO. But when I go to Tex.SE there is no option to login with a Connected-SO account (SO account connected to  Tex.SE). I created **My SO account with my GitHub account**; but there doesn't seem to be any options for that either.

Am I missing somewhere in authenticating or simply misunderstanding something? Why can't I log in to Tex.SE?

### Tex.SE login window

[image]

Feel free to comment and ask questions from me.

I **still get notification** updates from the Tex.SE posts from the SO notifications tab/the section in the bar, but I can't reply, upvote, and mark as answers, because I can't login.

One can notice that **I should/can/must answer this on Meta.SE**, but I **can't log in to it either** :( .

Abbreviations:

1. SO = Stack Overflow
2. Tex.SE = [Tex Stack exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com)
3. Meta.SE = [Meta Stack exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

### xample pop-up from ukranian.SE (not Tex.SE)

[image]

Comment: It's safer to just create an SE email credential as a backup. Github login is indeed only available on SO, just like Launchpad login only on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Andrew then what about the **pop-up i got when I went to sign-up in Tex.SE saying _would you like to connect and use/login using your SO account_ ?** If someone offers me to connect an account on A with the site B; then I should be able to login using the One on A because it doesnt make sense to offer one account connection thing, store it on a cookie on the primary computer and then just say _hey do you have an B account?_ **like  it is a flow** that It offers to connect. You dont address it, do you?

Comment: @AndrewT.  Thanks for the advice. Creating an backup is very valuable but **offering an account connection that _only works on one computer_ ?** Child(or even me) erased cookies? computer broken? _Yikes._ The window that first appears on Tex.SE should be removed. the window I am talking about -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409433/i-have-connected-my-stack-overflow-account-to-tex-se-and-meta-se-cant-login-wi#:~:text=pop-up%20i%20got%20when%20I%20went%20to%20sign-up%20in%20Tex.SE%20saying%20would%20you%20like%20to%20connect%20and%20use/login%20using%20your%20SO%20account